# Configure typescript to compile outside of Node or browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, sandbox, definition, typescript-definitions

I'm looking to create a sandboxed JavaScript environment, meaning standard node functions like `require()` or `process.*` shouldn't exist. And I would like TypeScript to reflect that. Instead I've got a custom `.d.ts` file that I would like to use as a standard definitions library. But I can't figure out how to override everything and provide just this one file. I've tried using the `lib` options in the tsconfig as well as `include` and `exclude`. I'd also like to mention that I don't what to have to include this file for every script to be sandboxed.

Can someone steer me in the right direction please?
Thanks

Comment: Look at how the standard library declarations provided by TypeScript are themselves composed and you should get an idea where to start.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't much help to me. I've created the definition file, but my issue lies in importing it.

Comment: Just add  `import 'path-to-my-lib.d.ts';` to your entry point or add use a `/// <reference types="path-to-my-lib">`. Alternately, publish it as an npm package and list it under `"types":["my-lib"]` in your tsconfig.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid having to import the file manually. Specifically include it in the tsconfig file as a library, much like how Promises are included and work without having to import them.

Comment: You can't reference it the same way as the `"lib.*"` entries. That field is for the TypeScript official declarations and is not a customization point AFAIK. It would be highly irregular to put it there even if it were possible. Reference it as a dependency package.

Comment: So how to runtimes like NodeJS and Deno do it? I know for a fact that Deno typings are not included in the official build of typescript, yet still are accessible without inports

Comment: The pattern for the NodeJS types is exactly what you should be following. They are versioned and come from the `@types/node` package. You have to install that package _and_, if you _explicitly_ list the global types that the compiler will make available, using the `"compilerOptions.types"` array, you have to list `"node"` there or its the types won't be available. Note you can install a local directory as a package with `your-package-manager install 'path-to-directory'` to test this out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220995/discussion-between-jacob-schneider-and-aluan-haddad).